# Why do some SQL Server databases go into a "Recovery Pending" state after shutting down / restarting on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, sql-server-2019, troubleshooting

I built a secondary PC from old parts as a server for SQL Server databases and I went with Linux/Ubuntu 20.04 because it's free. I knew it would not be easy to set this up (I'm rather a Windows user) and I had quite some issues/challenges along the way but I got it working.

My only headache now is that basically every time I shutdown or reboot the PC, some of the databases are getting the "Recovery pending" state and then I have to run the usual script to fix that. (which for some of my big DBs are taking quite a long time to finish)

I thought I need to manually stop the SQL Server services every time I shutdown the PC so I tried this before that:

```
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
```

Yet I still had one of the DBs in this pending state after booting. Now maybe the issue is that DB is on a different drive? The DBs not affected by this state are on the main SSD where Ubuntu is installed, if that makes any difference. I store the DBs on internal storage devices (1 SSD + 2 HDD).
Someone hinted on stackoverflow that maybe the HDDs were mounted AFTER the SQL Server services has been started? How could I fix that?

Thanks for any helpful feedback.

EDIT:
I checked the logs, the database files cannot be found:

[image]

This might prove that the SQL Server services start to early, I guess.

Comment: You'll have to look at the errorlog and potentially some DMVs to understand what resource the database is waiting on to recover. While in your case it's most likely that the file is unavailable at the time of database boot, the logs and DMVs will give you the actual answer.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the errorlog, edited the question.

Comment: Yep, so based on the log you're getting the file can't be found (which is why it then goes into recovery pending) which is most likley caused by the service coming up before all the disks/drives/network locations aren't available at the time the database is attempting to be opened and mounted.